# Figure changing place with different laptops

Tags: graphics, floats

I am working on a conference paper and I have a git repository, therefore I am sure that me and my supervisor are working on the same exact file.

I have the following problem: when I compile the file one figure goes somewhere in the pdf and when he does the figure goes somewhere else.

The first figure , (call it Figure A) is entered like this:

```
\begin{figure*}[t!]
\centering
\subfloat[]
{
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{exp16}
\label{fig:exp1_1}
}
\subfloat[]
{
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{exp16}
\label{fig:exp1_2}
}
\subfloat[]
{
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{exp16}
\label{fig:exp1_3}
}
\caption{\small \cref{fig:exp1_1} shows the behavior of...;~\cref{fig:exp1_2} is the dual of~\cref{fig:exp1_1} ...;~\cref{fig:exp1_3} shows the behavior of....}
\label{fig:exp1}
\end{figure*}
```

while the second picture is entered in this way:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
{
\includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{exp16}
}
\caption{\small Behavior of the ...~\cref{eq:rot}}
\label{fig:exp2}
\end{figure}
```

In my supervisor's case the fig fig:exp2 goes after fig:exp1 (as we want) and it becomes Fig.3 while fig:exp1 is Fig.2.

In my case the fig fig:exp2 goes before fig:exp1 (we don't want that) and it still becomes Fig.3 while fig:exp1 is Fig.2 (which is annoying).

Thanks for the help

EDIT: As suggested by @jfbu I put \listfiles in my preamble. You can find the result of log here:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.10.28) 18 SEP 2017 11:26
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(./ieeeconf.cls
Document Class: ieeeconf 2004/1/15 revision V1.6b by Pradeep Misra
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenA=\dimen102
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenB=\dimen103
\@IEEEtrantmpcountA=\count79
\@IEEEtrantmpcountB=\count80
\@IEEEtrantmptoksA=\toks14
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for OT1+ptm on input line 792.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
)
\@IEEEnormalsizefontbaselineskip=\skip41
-- This is a 10 point document.
\normalsizebaselineskip=\skip42
\normaljot=\skip43
```

Comment: you should investigate what is different in your TeX installations, adding `\listfiles` to the preamble and checking the log file for the file list which gives the details of package version numbers.

Comment: is your paper two-columns? why the `figure*` in first case?

Comment: Yeah. It is 2 columns. I used `figure*` to get the figure on multiple columns. I tried different ways, this was the smoothest.

Comment: first basic thing to check is whether `pdflatex` is used on both laptops or one uses `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Comment: I think that figures taking whole pagewidth are handled separately from one-column figures. As a result any change elsewhere might cause the changed positions. As the file is exactly the same, the difference is to be looked for in packages. If everything is exactly the same, then this becomes very interesting and make sure you keep a copy so that it does not get lost if by accident you solve your problem, because people will like to know about it.

Comment: is you file using some bibliographic database? is it the same then on both laptops?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the multiple comments. Yeah, we are using a database but it should be the same for both of us.

Comment: can you fetch the log file from the other laptop and make a diff with yours? (and especially after having added `\listfiles` to preamble)

Comment: (in my [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391915/figure-changing-place-with-different-laptops#comment973446_391915) above I should have said "difference is to be looked for in packages *or in latex*" as per @DavidCarlisle's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391925/4686) ...)

Comment: The files are too big to (in terms of number of characters) be posted here. I put a dropbox link or do you prefer another solution?

Comment: the diff between the too should be smaller.

Comment: I have no access to the other file for now. But I will come back here asap. Thanks

Comment: actually just the first 10 or so lines of the log will be enough in this case.

Comment: I added my log output.

Comment: `LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>` as guessed:-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Early (pre 2015) latex versions of latex had a documented deficiency that double column (`figure*`) floats were not kept in sequence with single column (`figure`) floats.

Three possible remedies.

1 (best) update both systems to the latest version of latex so they both do the same thing.

2 (OK) copy the package `latexrelease` from the newer system to the older system and then start the document with

```
\RequirePackage[latest]{latexrelease}
```

3 (probably works) add

```
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
```

at the start of the document to use the old "fix" package which fixed this (`fixltx2e` does nothing on newer releases)

Comment: The 3rd solution worked for me. Maybe the best, as you pointed out, is that I finally update my tex distribution.